# Failed to resolve: legacy-support-core-ui-1.0.0

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm trying to integrate appodeal's sdk. and when trying to sync the project with Gradle, this error show's up:

```
Failed to resolve: legacy-support-core-ui-1.0.0
```

here are the dependencies:

```
    dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.exifinterface:exifinterface:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-ui:1.0.0'

    //volley
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'

    //mpchart
    implementation 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.1.0'

    //Glide
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.11.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.11.0'

    //Calligraphy
    implementation 'io.github.inflationx:calligraphy3:3.1.1'
    implementation 'io.github.inflationx:viewpump:2.0.3'

    //appodeal
    implementation 'com.appodeal.ads:sdk:2.6.5.0'
}
```

Comment: if you use `implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-ui:1.0.0-alpha1'`?

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya , I just tried, same result, tnx

Answer (score 1):

**`androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-ui`**

> This artifact and its classes are deprecated. Starting with Android 8,
> background check restrictions make this class no longer useful.

You can remove

```
 implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-ui:1.0.0'
```

Then **`Clean-Rebuild-Restart`** IDE.

**FYI**

```
 implementation 'com.appodeal.ads:sdk:2.6.5.+'
```

Make sure you added below in project-level **`build.gradle`**

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
      
        maven {
            url "https://artifactory.appodeal.com/appodeal" // this is important
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ok, I just removed that line, but the error is still present

Comment: @RezaHamzehei Clean-Rebuild-Restart

Comment: @RezaHamzehei i mean `Failed to resolve: legacy-support-core-ui-1.0.0` error still showing after remove?

Comment: yes, the only way, the error disapears, is by removing this line
implementation 'com.appodeal.ads:sdk:2.6.5.0' , which I can't.

Comment: @RezaHamzehei Use `com.appodeal.ads.sdk:core:2.6.5`

Comment: @RezaHamzehei Solve this yet ?